# one to none-or-one relationship in ASP.NET MVC EF Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm new to .NET MVC and I'm struggling with using Code First with an existing database in which a table has a one to none-or-one (1 -> 0..1) relationship.

I have a report, which can have many sections, and each section can have many questions. Now here's the bit where I think I'm running into trouble... each question may have one answer or none.

I'm getting the following error:

> System.Data.Edm.EdmAssociationEnd: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role
>   'QuestionAnswer_Question_Source' in relationship
>   'QuestionAnswer_Question'. Because the Dependent Role properties are
>   not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the
>   Dependent Role must be �*�.

Here are my model classes:

**ModeratorReport.cs**

```
public class ModeratorReport
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int ModeratorReportID { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    public string FileYear { get; set; }
    public string SessionCode { get; set; }
    public string CentreNumber { get; set; }
    public string SubjectNumber { get; set; }
    public string PaperNumber { get; set; }
    public string ModeratorNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateModified { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AuditItem> Audit { get; set; }
}
```

**Section.cs**

```
public class Section
{
    [Key]
    public int SectionID { get; set; }
    public string SectionEnglish { get; set; }
    public string SectionWelsh { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}
```

**Question.cs**

```
public class Question
{
    [Key]
    public int QuestionID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Section")]
    public int SectionID { get; set; }

    public string QuestionEnglish { get; set; }
    public string QuestionWelsh { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public virtual Section Section { get; set; }
    public virtual QuestionAnswer QuestionAnswer { get; set; }
}
```

**QuestionAnswer.cs**

```
public class QuestionAnswer
{
    [Key]
    public int AnswerID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ModeratorReport"), Column(Order = 0)]
    public int ModeratorReportID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ModeratorReport"), Column(Order = 1)]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Section")]
    public int SectionID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Question")]
    public int QuestionID { get; set; }

    public string Answer { get; set; }

    public virtual ModeratorReport ModeratorReport { get; set; }
    public virtual Section Section { get; set; }
    public virtual Question Question { get; set; }
}
```

I also have a one-to-many relationship with ModeratorReport and Audit but I don't think that is what is causing the error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The EF is complaining because it sounds like you are using an FK Association - which means that the QuestionID is a property of the Entity and there is a Question reference too - and you can't do this with FK Associations.
if you remove the `QuestionID` from `QuestionAnswer` it should work

```
public class QuestionAnswer
{
    [Key,ForeignKey("Question")]]
    public int AnswerID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ModeratorReport"), Column(Order = 0)]
    public int ModeratorReportID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ModeratorReport"), Column(Order = 1)]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Section")]
    public int SectionID { get; set; }


    public string Answer { get; set; }

    public virtual ModeratorReport ModeratorReport { get; set; }
    public virtual Section Section { get; set; }
    public virtual Question Question { get; set; }
}
```

I would suggest you to use fluent mapping which is more clear:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Question>()
            .HasOptional(q => q.QuestionAnswer)

modelBuilder.Entity<QuestionAnswer>()
                .HasRequired(qa => qa.Question)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Massimiliano. The only trouble is that I'm using QuestionID in QuestionAnswer to retrieve an answer to a specific question and without the ID, I can't do that. Unless there is another way I can do that?    Also, I seem to get the error: `Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'Viewer.Models.QuestionAnswer' and 'Viewer.Models.Question'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.`

Comment: thanks very much. I often get confused with the fluent API but I'm starting to understand it now. It's nice to come in to work in the morning, and getting things working straight away! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should remove the QuestionId from the Answer entity in order to get it to work.
The fluent configuration then will be :

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Question>()
            .HasOptional(qa => qa.QuestionAnswer)
```

Also, if you want to use a navigation property on the Answer to retrieve the correspondent question, I guess that an answer should not exists without a question. You can then enforce the Id of the answer to be both PK and FK with the QuestionId. 
Add this to the configuration of the Answer :

```
modelBuilder.Entity<QuestionAnswer>()
                .HasRequired(qa => qa.Question)
```